# logic behind creating bookmark checksum in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How i can add a new bookmark entry in chrome bookmarkfile?. My requirement is, i need to add a bookmark entry through my application. Please specify the logic behind creating checksum(MD5).

Comment: For creating md5 check sums, see the CryptoJS library: http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#MD5

Answer (score 6):

Regardless of the safety/hackishness of doing it, here's how:

1. Make sure Chrome is closed.
2. Delete (or rename) `Bookmarks.bak`
3. Remove the checksum entry entirely from `Bookmarks`
4. Edit the `Bookmarks` JSON to your hearts content
5. Reopen Chrome

When presented with no backups and no checksum, Chrome will use the new JSON and generate a new checksum.

If you would like to do this more seamlessly / less aggressively, you can just look at how they generate the checksum in the original source code and implement the same algorithm (see [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/master/chrome/browser/bookmarks/bookmark_codec.cc), on line 57).

Of course, keep in mind that Google can change things that could break compatibility. However, this does work, I just did it in a Java app I wrote.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously this is hackish and only meant for people who know what they are doing, but, since Chrome Mobile does not let the user export/import their own bookmarks (not exactly user-friendly!), sometimes there's no choice - imagine having to clean up a Bookmarks file with thousands of entries by hand.

Anyway, here's a working Python implementation:

```py
roots = ['bookmark_bar', 'other', 'synced']

def checksum_bookmarks(bookmarks):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()

    def checksum_node(node):
        md5.update(node['id'].encode())
        md5.update(node['name'].encode('utf-16le'))
        if node['type'] == 'url':
            md5.update(b'url')
            md5.update(node['url'].encode())
        else:
            md5.update(b'folder')
            if 'children' in node:
                for c in node['children']:
                    checksum_node(c)

    for root in roots:
        checksum_node(bookmarks['roots'][root])
    return md5.hexdigest()
```

As long as you're only adding bookmarks, you're probably fine, but for anything more complex (e.g. doing major cleanups, editing and deleting bookmarks, especially when multiple devices are involved), be sure to reset "Chrome Sync", or it will give you back all the deleted stuff, and an extra copy of each altered bookmark:
 Settings -> Sync -> Manage synced data -> Reset Sync

Answer (score 3):

My advice: not to.
It is hack-like behaviour.  Chrome doesn't include the bookmark file in its "API", and it can change without warning.  We don't know what happens if you change the file while Chrome is running.  Does Chrome read that file every time before writing?  Or it is read only once at start-up?  What about profiles and synchronizing bookmarks?

I recommend using the bookmark object in Chrome's extension API.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the age of the post, the answer is still relevant for those seeking a script to generate the checksum.

Here is my NodeJS solution, inspired by the Python and Chromium source.

```
import { createHash } from 'crypto';

const regenChecksum = (roots) => {
    const digest = createHash('md5');
    const digestUrl = (url) => {
        digest.update(url['id'], 'ascii');
        digest.update(url['name'], 'utf16le');
        digest.update(Buffer.from('url'));
        digest.update(url['url'], 'ascii');
    };

    const digestFolder = (folder) => {
        digest.update(folder['id'], 'ascii');
        digest.update(folder['name'], 'utf16le');
        const bytes = Buffer.from('folder');
        digest.update(bytes);
        folder['children']?.forEach((child) => {
            updateDigest(child);
        });

    };

    const updateDigest = (node) => {
        node.type === 'folder' ? digestFolder(node) : digestUrl(node);
    };

    updateDigest(roots['bookmark_bar']);
    updateDigest(roots['other']);
    updateDigest(roots['synced']);
    return digest.digest('hex');
};
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/dcantu476/ac8d4ae63a6a22c6a6fda7d8f9fb3039

Answer (score 0):

Here is C# solution:

```cs
public static string CalculateCheckSum(string bookmarksText)
{
    var bytes = new List<byte>();

    void DigestUrl(JToken url)
    {
        bytes.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url["id"].Value<string>()!));
        bytes.AddRange(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(url["name"].Value<string>()!));
        bytes.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("url"));
        bytes.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url["url"].Value<string>()!));
    }

    void DigestFolder(JToken folder)
    {
        bytes.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(folder["id"].Value<string>()!));
        bytes.AddRange(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(folder["name"].Value<string>()!));
        bytes.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("folder"));

        foreach (var item in folder["children"])
        {
            if (item?["type"]?.Value<string>() == "folder")
            {
                DigestFolder(item);
            }
            else
            {
                DigestUrl(item);
            }
        }
    }

    var json = JToken.Parse(bookmarksText);

    DigestFolder(json["roots"]?["bookmark_bar"]);
    DigestFolder(json["roots"]?["other"]);
    DigestFolder(json["roots"]?["synced"]);

    using var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    var result = md5.ComputeHash(bytes.ToArray());

    return BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}
```

First use `File.ReadAllText` method to read all text from the `bookmarks` file, then call this method.